# Showing a set is a Borel set and its probability is $0$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $P(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1_X(x) f(x) \,dx $ for $f(x) \geq 0 $ for all $x$ such that $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx = 1 $. Suppose $A = \{ x_0 \} $. Then $A$ is a Borel set and $P(A) = 0 $.

#### Attempt

By definition, I know that if $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of all closed sets, then Borel sigma algebra is the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal{F} $, denoted by $\mathcal{B}( \mathcal{F} ) $. We know singletons are closed sets, hence $A = \{ x_0 \} \in \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{F} ) $ and so $A$ is a borel set. Is this a correct argument?

Next, to show that $P(A) = 0$, notice $1_A(x)f(x) = f $ if $x = x_0$ and $0$ otherwise, hence
$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} 1_A(x) f(x) \,dx = \int_{x_0}^{x_0} f(x) = 0. $$

Is this sufficient?

Comment: Your argument seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer to remove the question from the Unanswered queue:

The proof is okay.